# How to read string in the selected region in pdf viewer of .NET language

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am coding using VB 2010. I have inserted the pdf viewer object box which works fine. But I currently want to read the string(Mostly picture numbers) which the user clicks/selects in the PDF viewer of VB.

- Should i convert the whole PDF into text and read from that somehow? Or
- Can i provide some hyperlinks on the PDF which could be used to
  identify?

Comment: what do you mean by Mostly picture numbers ??

Comment: actually the pdf would be of any plan/elevation of building with different sections at different locations. So once they click on the section i want to read the detail number so that i can open that file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating the pdf at some point, you can simply insert external links (for instance to other documents). You could also create a pdf that contains all the plans, and use internal links (same concept).

For more details, check out the pdf specification (page 622)
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf